# Contravariance and Entity Framework 4.0: how to specify EntityCollection as IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, covariance

I have specified a couple of interfaces, which I am implementing as entities using Entity Framework 4.  The simplest demonstration code I can come up with is:

```
public class ConcreteContainer : IContainer
{
    public EntityCollection<ConcreteChild> Children { get; set; }           
}
public class ConcreteChild : IChild
{
}
public interface IContainer
{
    IEnumerable<IChild> Children { get; set; }
}
public interface IChild
{        
}
```

I receive the following compiler error from the above:

> 'Demo.ConcreteContainer' does
>   not implement interface member
>   'Demo.IContainer.Children'.
>   'Demo.ConcreteContainer.Children'
>   cannot implement
>   'Demo.IContainer.Children'
>   because it does not have the matching
>   return type of
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

My current understanding is that this is because [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28VS.100%29.aspx) (which is implemented by EntityCollection) is covariant but presumably not contravariant:

> This type parameter is covariant. That is, you can use 
>   either the type you specified or any type that is more 
>   derived. For more information about covariance and contravariance,
>   see Covariance and Contravariance in Generics.

Am I correct, & if so, is there any way I can achieve my goal of specifying the `IContainer` interface purely in terms of other interfaces rather than using concrete classes?

Or, am I misunderstanding something more fundamental?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generic variance in .NET 4 is irrelevant here. The *implementation* of an interface has to match the interface signature *exactly* in terms of types.

For example, take `ICloneable`, which looks like this:

```
public interface ICloneable
{
    object Clone();
}
```

It would be *nice* to be able to implement it like this:

```
public class Banana : ICloneable
{
    public Banana Clone() // Fails: this doesn't implement the interface
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

... but .NET doesn't allow this. You can sometimes use *explicit interface implementation* work around this, like so:

```
public class Banana : ICloneable
{
    public Banana Clone()
    {
        ...
    }

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return Clone(); // Delegate to the more strongly-typed method
    }
}
```

However, in your case you can't ever do that. Consider the following code, which would be valid if `ConcreteContainer` was considered to implement `IContainer`:

```
IContainer foo = new ConcreteContainer();
foo.Children = new List<IChild>();
```

Now your property setter is actually only declared to work with `EntityCollection<ConcreteChild>`, so it clearly can't work with *any* `IEnumerable<IChild>` - in violation of the interface.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, you must implement an interface - you can't assume that a covariant/contra-variant member would be picked up as a substitute.
Even if it was permissible, note that setter for children is an issue. Because it will allow to set property of type *`EntityCollection<ConcreteChild>`* with value of any other type such as `List<ConcreteChild>` or `EntityCollection<ConcreteChild2>` because both are implementing `IEnumerable<IChild>`.

In current design, I will implement IContainer privately in ConcreteContainer and check the input value in IEnumerable.Children setter for a compatible type. Another way to approach this design is to have generic interfaces such as:

```
public interface IContainer<T> where T:IChild
{
    IEnumerable<T> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions.  The Generic interface approach is nice, but doesn't work with EF4, which makes EF4 quite challenging to mock in entirety when unit testing.  As a result, we've moved primarily to integration testing for EF entities.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to implement this interface, right?

```
public interface IContainer
{
    IEnumerable<IChild> Children { get; set; }
}
```

But in the real class, you want the property to be of type `EntityCollection<ConcreteChild>`. Here’s how you can do this:

```
public class ConcreteContainer : IContainer
{
    // This is the property that will be seen by code that accesses
    // this instance through a variable of this type (ConcreteContainer)
    public EntityCollection<ConcreteChild> Children { get; set; }           

    // This is the property that will be used by code that accesses
    // this instance through a variable of the type IContainer
    IEnumerable<ConcreteChild> IContainer.Children {
        get { return Children; }
        set {
            var newCollection = new EntityCollection<ConcreteChild>();
            foreach (var item in value)
                newCollection.Add(item);
            Children = newCollection;
        }
    }
}
```